# NestJs, unable to connect to the database using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, arm, nestjs, raspbian

I'm working on a nestjs mongoose project. The code have to run on an a raspberry (32 bit OS). The code on my devel machine works well, but when I run it on raspberry I'm not able to connect to mongodb.

This is my configuration:

```
board: raspberry pi 4
OS: raspbian buster 32 bit
Kernel: Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7l+
nestjs: 9.1.1
mongo: 2.4.14
mongoose: 
   "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.3
   "mongoose": "^6.2.2"
```

I try to connect to mongo from AppModule, using this code:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbtest',
    { 
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
    ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I already tryed those solutions (none works):

- 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as connection address,
- ?directConnection=true attached at the end of connection string
- update to mongoose 6.2.2
- deleted useNewUrlParser: true from configuration's parameters

this is the nest's log:

```
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +210ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigurationModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtwrapperModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:17:51     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 28715  - 04/09/2022, 11:18:21   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
```

can anyone give me any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Do you have mongoose running on the raspberry pi?

Comment: I have mongodb running, I can use mongo shell to connect to db. How can I check if mongoose is running?

Comment: Is it running on the raspberry pi? If so, can you let the retries timeout (there's 10 of them) and get a more details error message?

Comment: I did, I waited until retries end. The error is related to the mongo version. the 2.4 is too old, mongoose driver needs a version 6 (if I remember well), that coincides with a mongo greater than 4 (always if remenber well)